# MFMessageComposeViewController and UIAppearance, apple says don't customize

Tags: ios5, containment, uiappearance

Question

In the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) for MFMessageComposeViewController apple says:

> **Important** The message composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

But navigationbar and barbuttonitems in the MFMessageComposeViewController and the MFMailComposeViewController are inheriting all the styling I've done through UIAppearance.

I tried to revert to default appearance by using UIAppearance containment and setting the navigationbar/barbuttonitem background images to nil, but I couldn't figure out how to restore the default titleTextAttributes for the navigationbar and barbuttonitem.

I tried going the other route and using containment to restrict the styling to my navigation controller, but it seems like MFMessageComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController are contained within my navigaton controller anyway, so this isn't helping.

So my questions are:

1) will changing the navbar appearance on MFMessageComposeView and MFMailComposeView be an issue at app store approval? (if it's not an issue I can keep the custom styles.)

2) is there a way to present the ComposeViewController so that it won't be contained within my navigation controller?

3) or simply, how can i restore the default title text attributes for the barButtonItems and navigationBar?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a rather old question, but:

1). No, changing appearance of navigation bar will not affect AppStore approval. Mentioned Apple note is related to fields of MFMessageComposeViewController (e.g. To: Cc: ...), not the navigation bar. (We had an approved app with such customized navbar)

2, 3) No need for that =)